# Options to find an analytical description of some points

Tags: splines, findformula

I have a set of points {{x1,y1},...{xn,yn}} and I would like to have the analytical expression of a function that describes them reasonably well. So that I can plot this function on a `LogLinearPlot`. I have attempted `FindFormula` but no success. What are other options? Would Splines work?

```
points = {{353.85`, 167.41585386436694`}, {55.05`, 
    141.09889559222094`}, {8.745000000000001`, 
    107.584805589005`}, {5.555`, 98.2002870640922`}, {4.245`, 
    92.29910430810045`}, {2.505`, 
    79.83755719046736`}, {1.5350000000000001`, 
    65.24569514564583`}, {0.8150000000000001`, 
    35.95626014295387`}, {0.5750000000000001`, 28.27836024608773`}};
```

Comment: You can `Rationalize` them. If they are integers, you can attempt to use `FindSequenceFunction`. If you see fractions, work the numerator and denominator separately. If not integers, you can try `FindFit` if approximate is enough for your purposes. These are just some suggestions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It all depends on the required accuracy. Is the following good enough?

```
fit = LinearModelFit[dat, {x^(1/5), x^(1/7), x^(1/9)}, x]
```

[image]

```
Plot[fit[x], {x, 0.37, 354}, Epilog -> Point[dat], PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: What a clever "ansatz":

Comment: @Ulrich Neumann The idea behind the "ansatz" is to use functions with approx. the right shape like x^a where a<1 instead of polynomials.

Comment: Indead , I only tried `Sqrt[x],Sqrt[x]^2,...`  in the first part of my answer

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
fit = NonlinearModelFit[points,a Sqrt[x] + b x + c Sqrt[x]^3 + d  x^2 , {a, b, c, d}, x]
Show[{ListPlot[points], Plot[fit[x], {x, 0, Max[points[[All, 1]]]}]},PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

**addendum**

If you 're interested in a "monoton fit" try instead

```
fit = NonlinearModelFit[points, {a (1  + b x - c/(c + x))  , c > 0 }, {a, b, c }, x, Method -> "NMinimize"]
Show[{ListPlot[points],Plot[fit[x], {x, 0, Max[points[[All, 1]]]},PlotRange -> All]} ]
```

[image]

LogLinearPlot:

```
Show[{LogLinearPlot[fit[x], {x, 0, Max[points[[All, 1]]]},PlotRange -> All], ListPlot[Map[{Log[#[[1]]], #[[2]]} &, points], PlotRange -> All]}]
```

[image]

Hope it helps!

Comment: indeed, the 'monotonic fit' seems more realistic. It would be great if it would start to flatten off (tend to a plateau) at large x values

Comment: Perhaps `  a (1   - c/(c + x))` ?